# Паттерн проектирования - ms sql и xml

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server

Приходят xml (средний размер около 2 Гб) и xsd, мне необходимо часть информации из них добавить в базу данных ms sql. Есть ли какие-нибудь паттерны проектирования или принятые нормы в данном случае? Что использовать - промежуточную встраиваемую базу или есть более красивые решения?

update Данный XML это по сути таблица, там корневой тег, а в нем одинаковые теги, в которых множество одинаковых атрибутов с различными значениями, грубо говоря двумерная таблица. Мне из данной XML нужна только часть данных, которые мне необходимо добавить на рабочую базу.

Comment: Конкретизируй вопрос. В XML данные относятся к одной таблице или к многим? Xml - это отображение документа с множественными структурами или слепок одной таблицы?

Comment: @MaLS обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Для загрузки большого объема данных в MSSQL нужно использовать [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Данные из файла нужно будет прочитать и отфильтровать в потоковом режиме при этом тебе надо будет реализовать интерфейс `IDataReader`. Пример есть тут [IDataReader implementation + SqlBulkCopy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228332/IDataReader-implementation-plus-SqlBulkCopy).

Потоковое чтение из XML можно сделать с помощью [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: потоковое чтение чрез XmlReader понятно, но как их связать потом с IDataReader нет

Comment: разве пример [IDataReader implementation + SqlBulkCopy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228332/IDataReader-implementation-plus-SqlBulkCopy) не разъясняет? Тогда это другой большой вопрос.

Comment: обновил вопрос, как это связать с IDataReader не пойму

Comment: Ты исказил суть текущего вопроса. Пожалуйста удали изменения и задай новый "Как связать IDaraReader c XmlReder для SqlBulkCopy?" потому, что это уже другая тема.

Comment: Хорошо, спс за исправление

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна только часть данных, тогда используйте LINQ to XML. Там можно задавать условия отбора.

1. Вот [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/24673/) на эту тему.
2. А вот как [работать с большими файлами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387013.aspx)
3. Здесь описан [класс XStreamingElemeнт](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Размер xml хоть 1 терабайт. Используйте XDocument. С помощью него я обрабатывал файлы в несколько гигабайт, при этом скорость выборки данных была вполне комфортна. Заливать в базу можно и с помощью ADO.NET. Он использует отложенный commit в БД.

Comment: А как вы грузите в XDocument большие файлы?